# Subquery : trying to add 1 more column

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm novice with SQL. Actually, I'm trying to add a new column to this :

```sql
SELECT ville_departement, COUNT(*) FROM villes_france_free 
GROUP BY ville_departement
HAVING ville_departement IN
(SELECT ville_departement FROM departement
INNER JOIN villes_france_free 
ON departement.departement_code = villes_france_free.ville_departement);
```

I have the number of cities from each departements. But in addition of departement_code, I want to show departement_name on the final result

Problem : Obviously, I can't confront 1 column with 2.

The link between departement_code and departement_name is defined as : there is one departement_code for several departement_name.

Thanks for your help !! :)

Léandre

Comment: Please add the DB schema for the affected tables (table names, column names, column types...), the entire query you built and the desired output you want to have. Thank you.

Comment: I think you want something like 
`SELECT ville_departement, department_name, COUNT(*) FROM villes_france_free 
INNER JOIN departement on  departement.departement_code = villes_france_free.ville_departement
GROUP BY ville_departement, department_name`

Comment: Thanks a lot Jonas !!

Answer (score 0):

To update my awser to the other post

```
SELECT 
      departement_code, 
      departement_nom,
      COUNT(*) as NombreVilles
FROM 
      villes_france_free as ville inner join
      departement on departement.departement_code = ville.ville_departement
GROUP BY 
      departement_code, 
      departement_nom
HAVING 
      ville_departement IN ( Your filter ) --- No need to put a subquery select in here
```